# C Code to count how many letters in a word

Tags: c, string, function, loops

I made simple code to count how many letters in a word, for some reason the variables `letters` is not consistent, here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str;
    int slen(char *str)
    {
        int i;
        int letters=0;
        for(i=0;i<30;i++)
        {
            if((str[i]>='A'&&str[i]<='Z')||(str[i]>='a'&&str[i]<='z'))
                letters++;
        }
        return letters;
    }
    printf("%d \n", slen("Word"));
}
```

The variable `letter` here prints 22.

Comment: And what output do you expect?

Comment: Why are you doing `<30` in your `for` condition? That means the loop will overrun the end of the string itself and start counting garbage data that happens to be in memory.

Comment: I think you need to write in the for loop `<str.size`

Comment: @STF it's tagged as C, not C++.

Comment: Do you know about [`isalpha()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha)?

Comment: @Steve you are right - but he need to loop on the string size and not on 30 because he is reading spam there.

Comment: nested function is a GNU extension, not standard C.

Comment: @STF - yep, `strlen` is the way to go here rather than `.size()`

Comment: @Steve I fixed it by setting the 'for' to stop the loop once is find a space ' ', thank you the code now works perfectly i did not know that it could find garbage data in the memory since i am new to C language.

Comment: @TheErolley I'll defer to your judgement about whether that fixes it, but it doesn't appear to - your input string doesn't contain a space and there is no guarantee that the garbage data will or won't contain one. There are several correct answers posted below.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the `< 30` condition in your `for` loop, your program goes past the `"Word"` string boundaries and starts calculating whatever's in memory right after that string.

Replace `< 30` with `< strlen(str)` (you're going to need to `#include <string.h>`).

**UPDATE**: (kudos to @J...S (seee comments)) alternatively you can rewrite

```
for (i=0; i < 30; i++)
{
    if((str[i]>='A'&&str[i]<='Z')||(str[i]>='a'&&str[i]<='z'))
        letters++;
}
```

with

```
while (str != '\0') {
    if ((*str >= 'A' && *str <= 'Z') || (*str >= 'a' && *str <= 'z')) {
        letters++;
    }
    ++str;
}
```

You could also use something like `isalpha()` instead of your `if` condition.

And, by the way, *please* use spaces to separate different parts of a line. Otherwise it's really hard to read. Thanks :)

Comment: `str[i]!='\0'` may also be used.

Answer (score 2):

The function should be declared/defined outside `main()`.

Change this:

```
for(i=0;i<30;i++)
```

to this:

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
```

because you want to iterate over the length of the string, and not more or less than its actual length.

In your case, "Word" had just 4 letters, and you iterated until `i < 30` evaluated to false, invoking Undefined Behavior, since you would access memory that is out of bounds.

Putting everything together, we get:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int slen(char *str)
{
    int letters=0;
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)
    {
        if((str[i]>='A'&&str[i]<='Z')||(str[i]>='a'&&str[i]<='z'))
        letters++;
    }
    return letters;
}

int main()
{ 
    printf("%d \n", slen("Word"));
}
```

Output:

> 4

Comment: If you are using strlen then what is the use of for loop?

Comment: @AniruddhAgarwal - because the code isn't meant to be counting the number of characters, which is what `strlen` does. It's counting the number of __letters__. So you need to iterate through the entire string, hence the use of both the `for` loop and the `strlen`

Comment: I think what author has asked is how to count the characters in a word and strlen does what he wants

Comment: No @AniruddhAgarwal. He wants to count letters. A string can contain alphanumerical characters.

Comment: Okay okay, I got it now.

Comment: @AniruddhAgarwal You're wrong, the code specifically only checks letters (upper and lower case). It doesn't check for whitespace, punctuation or numbers.

Comment: @gsamaras Strictly speaking this phrase "The function should be declared/defined outside main()." is wrong.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow help me improve my answer =) How do you suggest rephrasing it?

Comment: @gsamaras I would suggest entirely my answer instead.:)

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


// declaring slen outside main (not using non standard GNU extension)

int slen(char *str) 
{
  int i;
  int letters = 0;
  int length = strlen(str);  // using strlen, in order not to go beyond the end
                             // of the string


  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if ((str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z') || (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z'))
      letters++;
  }

  return letters;
}

int main()
{
   printf("%d \n", slen("Word123"));
}
```

Expected output here is 4 (4 lettres of "Word", not counting digits 1,2, and 3).

Slighly optimized version:

```
int slen(char *str) 
{
  int letters = 0;

  for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
    char c = str[i];
    if (c == 0)
      break;

    if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'))
      letters++;
  }

  return letters;
}
```

and even better using `isalpha` from `ctype.h`:

```
#include <ctype.h>
...
int slen(char *str) 
{
  int letters = 0;
  for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
    int c = str[i];    // yes, int is correct, isalpha wants an int    
    if (c == 0)
      break;

    if (isalpha(c))
      letters++;
  }

  return letters;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Though some compilers can have their own language extensions nevertheless again according to the C Standard you may not define a function inside another function.

Also take into account that it is not necessary that Latin letters follow each other sequentially in a given character set. For example in the EBCDIC set some letters do not follow sequentially each other. There are embedded other symbols between letters.

So it is better to use standard C function `isalpha` declared in the header `<ctype.h>`.

Also the original string is not changed in the function. So it should be declared with the qualifier `const`.

And it is unclear why this magic number `30` is used in this loop within the function

```
for(i=0;i<30;i++)
```

Taking all this into account the program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

size_t letters_count( const char *s )
{
    size_t count = 0;

    for ( ; *s; ++s )
    {
        if ( isalpha( ( unsigned char )*s ) ) ++count;
    }

    return count;
}

#define N   100

int main(void) 
{
    char s[N];

    printf( "Enter a statement: " );

    fgets( s, sizeof( s ), stdin );

    printf( "The statement contains %zu letters\n", letters_count( s ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter a statement: Hello TheErolley
The statement contains 15 letters
```